# Convert datetime object in a particular timezone to epoch seconds in that timezone

Tags: python, datetime, timezone-offset, timestamp-with-timezone

eg:

`>>> print dt`
`2012-12-04 19:00:00-05:00`

As you can see, I have this datetime object 
How can I convert this datetime object to epoch seconds in GMT -5.

How do I do this?

Comment: Epoch seconds do not exist by timezone. By definition they are UTC and are the same worldwide.  Each timezone converts on the fly for local time.

Comment: @jimmcnamara That's the key. Extremely helpful, sir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your datetime is not a naive datetime, it knows about the timezone it's in (your print states that is -5). So you just need to set it as utc before you convert it to epoch

```
>>> import time, pytz
>>> utc = pytz.timezone('UTC')
>>> utc_dt = utc.normalize(dt.astimezone(utc))
>>> time.mktime(utc_dt.timetuple())
1355270789.0 # This is just to show the format it outputs
```

If the dt object was a naive datetime object, you'd need to work with time zones to comply to daylight saving time while finding the correct hours between GMT 0. For example, Romania in the winter, it has +2 and in the summer +3.

For your -5 example, New-York will do:

```
>>> import time,pytz
>>> timezone = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
>>> local_dt = timezone.localize(dt)
```

Now you have a non-naive datetime and you can get the epoch time like I first explained.
Have fun

Comment: Presumably the "-05:00" already codes the proper offset for the given date and time zone, so why go to the trouble of working backwards?

Comment: Thank you, I missed the -5 in the print. I adapted the answer to explain how to convert from non-naive datetime aswell.